# TextBlob, totally inaccurate

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk, textblob

Looking at responses from a recent survey we did. I do not think this respondent is all that happy. Here, TextBlob would have me believe his sentiment has reached a positive ceiling. If I remove the word 'best' from the string sentiment score turns to '0'.

Would you help to re-instill my trust is TextBlob, what am I doing wrong in this very simple application?

```
a = "Follow on rounds for the best prospects. Some choke to death now."
b = TextBlob(a)
print b.sentiment
```

*Sentiment(polarity=1.0, subjectivity=0.3)*

Thanks,

Comment: Why would you trust a tool called «TextBlob» in the first place?

Comment: To be more serious: TextBlob uses some pretrained models (about which you don't have to care when using the tool), but they're not perfect, as isn't any NLP task. If you want to improve the tool, you need to customise, re-train, try different things... Welcome to NLP!

Answer (score 9):

You need to understand that a machine, even after learning few things, is not a human. The statement "Follow on rounds for the best prospects. Some choke to death now." is a bit confusing even for a human to identify the sentiment as there seems to be less or no relation between the first and second statement.

Also, you may see many other genuine cases where polarity is opposite of something very obvious. If you need to deal with many such cases, you can the following code which may improve your results drastically.

```
from textblob import TextBlob
from textblob.sentiments import NaiveBayesAnalyzer
a = "Follow on rounds for the best prospects. Some choke to death now."
b = TextBlob(a, analyzer=NaiveBayesAnalyzer()))
print(b.sentiment)
```

For your example(which I personally believe is not a good one and confusing even for humans) here is the result:
`Sentiment(classification='pos', p_pos=0.5730186699265399, p_neg=0.42698133007345906)`

It is still positive, but you can see the difference between the pos and neg scores. For me it has been successful most of the time with relevant & meaningful sentences.

For explanation of what was changed in code, see below:

> The textblob.sentiments module contains two sentiment analysis implementations, PatternAnalyzer (based on the pattern library) and NaiveBayesAnalyzer (an NLTK classifier trained on a movie reviews corpus).
>
> The default implementation is PatternAnalyzer, but you can override the analyzer by passing another implementation into a TextBlob’s constructor.